# Easier way to dynamically render components with sidebar navigation using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

Currently going through this tutorial on creating a sidebar navigation system with react router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

I am planning to have multiple routes, so that means I'll have to keep importing the routes and add them to the `routes` array. Is there a smart/right way to load them dynamically?

All my components will be in my `/Views` folder.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar/SideBar';
import MainContent from './components/MainContent/MainContent';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
} from 'react-router-dom';


// Import all components here
import Button from './components/Views/Button/Button';
import Color from './components/Views/Color/Color';
import Card from './components/Views/Card/Card';
import Filter from './components/Views/Filter/Filter';

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: 'home',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/button",
    name: 'Button',
    main: () =>  <Button />
  },
  {
    path: "/color",
    name: 'Color',
    main: () =>  <Color />
  },
  {
    path: "/card",
    name: 'Card',
    main: () =>  <Card />
  },
  {
    path: "/filter",
    name: 'Filter',
    main: () =>  <Filter />
  },
];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="ds-container">
          <SideBar routes={routes} />
          <MainContent routes={routes} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using webpack to bundle?

Comment: Im just using whatever `create-react-app` is giving me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you're using create-react-app that uses webpack internally, you could look into `require-context`. This will help you dynamically import all files in a folder that match a certain regex. (ex: ending with .jsx/.js)

However, I'd advice you against it as:

1. At no point will you know what routes you're currently catering to.
2. It may decrease your code readability.
3. You may have to also export the mapping(`path` in the Route) of the component along with the component itself.

To avoid all of this, You could simply create a `index.js` file in your `Views` component that would require any new route component that you create and return the final array that you have formed in the `App.js` file.

So essentially, **/Views/index.js** :

```
// Import all components here
import Button from './components/Views/Button/Button';
import Color from './components/Views/Color/Color';
import Card from './components/Views/Card/Card';
import Filter from './components/Views/Filter/Filter';

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: 'home',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <h2>Home</h2>
  },
  {
    path: "/button",
    name: 'Button',
    main: () =>  <Button />
  },
  {
    path: "/color",
    name: 'Color',
    main: () =>  <Color />
  },
  {
    path: "/card",
    name: 'Card',
    main: () =>  <Card />
  },
  {
    path: "/filter",
    name: 'Filter',
    main: () =>  <Filter />
  },
  // add new routes here
];

export default routes;
```

In **SideBar.js**:

```
import routes from 'path/to/views/Views';

//rest of your code to render the routes.
```

This way, you would clean up the code in your App.js and would also be able to effectively separate the concerns of the individual components.

I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to choose a main component depending on current location. But all of them would require listing all the possible routes and importing respective components. You can use [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) and [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy) for easier code splitting.

But you can avoid extra configuration for your sidebar. The sidebar can get configuration from global state and your main components can update that state on mount (`componentDidMount` or `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`):

```
const SideBarContext = React.createContext(() => {});

function useSidebar(name) {
  const setSidebarName = useContext(SideBarContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSidebarName(name);
    return () => setSidebarName(null);
  }, []);
}

function Home() {
  useSidebar('home');
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function Button() {
  useSidebar('Button');
  return <button>press me</button>;
}

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="ds-container">
          <SideBar name={name} />
          <SideBarContext.Provider value={setName}>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/button" component={Button}/>
          </SideBarContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

So each component will take care about options for sidebar and you only need to import them and add `Route`s.